# Allow certain user to log in without keying in password in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, passwords, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp v3. I have enabled authentication. Suppose I want a user named "XXX" to login without using password. I have the following login() function in UsersController.php. How can it be modified to allow a user named "XXX" to login without needing to enter password?

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
} //public function login()
```

Comment: Just check if the posted username is 'XXX', if so, fetch the user from the DB instead of Auth->identify. If cake is sensible then passing the user object from the DB ORM to Auth->setUser should work as well. Disclaimer: never used cake3

Comment: Honestly this is a freaking stupid idea and opens a security hole. A dead simple dictionary attack that runs for some time *might* discover this account name if it's not a string like an UUID for example. And I doubt it's that complicated if this specific user is to lazy to enter a password. I would add at least a mechanism that prevents login attempts in short time and log them.

Comment: I agree with you. Cannot be helped if the user insists despite the warnings(minus the freakingly stupid remark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should probably work. Just make sure you use the correct method to fetch the correct param for the user name, and likewise for the user in the database.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $username = $this->request->data['username'];

        if (username === 'XXX') {
            $user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->find()->where(['username' => $username]);
        } else {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        }

        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. May I ask what is the purpose of `$user = TableRegistry::get('Users')->find()->where(['username' => $username]);`?

Comment: @user768421 using the orm to fetch the user from the db. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html

Comment: The code looked fine. But there were some error messages. http://pastebin.com/spsq7jMn

Comment: @user768421 tried to just convert the user object received from the db into an array?

Comment: I edited your answer and the error messages have been removed. However, the edit has been rejected by reviewers. Please review.

Comment: @user768421 I can't see the review, don't know if they get deleted on rejection. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91823/discussion-between-jiml-and-user768421).